Any experience with annotation(TestCase(shouldFail=false))?
I'm struggling with the annotation TestCase, which seems to have appeared in Modelica language 3.5 in early 2021.
Has anyone used it successfully with Dymola or OpenModelica ?
Here is a sample code I'm using to test it. The simulation fails, which should normaly be prevented by the annotation TestCase. Any suggestion to make it work on these platforms ?
model Test
  Boolean a;
equation 
  a = time < 0.5;

  assert(
    a,
    "test has failed: time is above 0.5",
    level=AssertionLevel.error);
  annotation (TestCase(shouldPass=false));
end Test;


For Dymola:

It only has effect if the model is inside a package you check.
Normally it just causes the check to be skipped. One part is that only models with experiment-annotations will actually be simulated, and this model only fails during simulation.

So consider the following:
package P
  model Test
    Boolean a;
  equation 
    a = time < 0.5;

    assert(
      a,
      "test has failed: time is above 0.5",
      level=AssertionLevel.error);
    annotation (experiment(StopTime=1), TestCase(shouldPass=false));
  end Test;
  model Test2
    annotation (TestCase(shouldPass=true));
  end Test2;
end P;

Checking P will skip Test.
Addendum: In Dymola 2024x Refresh 1 and earlier even check with simulation will just skip them, later versions should give a summary of issues.
A work-around for Dymola 2024x Refresh 1 is to instead use:
annotation(__ModelicaAssociation(TestCase(shouldPass=false))) which was an earlier solution for the same problem.

my understanding of the modelica language specification 18.4 If shouldPass is false it indicates that the translation or the simulation of the model should fail. is that it also concern simulations results. So I understand for the time being, for the simulation of test-case models that purposely fails, I need to manage results outside this annotation ?

It depends on the use. The TestCase(shouldPass=false) has some impact, but it will not yet ensure that the model fails to simulate in Dymola. If you use __ModelicaAssociation(TestCase(shouldPass=false)) that is tested as well, provided you do "Check with simulation" for the entire package. However, neither works yet if you simulate that specific model.
